Problem: Incorrect displaying of time difference (in months) between Python and Oracle
The background of my problem is:

there's SQL query in Python that extracts particular data from Oracle database
one column/information that is extracted from Oracle is information about how long a customer has open account by the company (in years)

The particular part of the query:
ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, TO_DATE(c.registration_date, 'dd.mm.yy')) / 12, 1) AS Years_Client
The problem:

when I run the query in Oracle (SQL Developer), I receive correct values
BUT when I run the query within Python code, it returns a column that contains both negative values or really high values (e.g. 21), which in the first place is a nonsense and in the second as well (as the company even doesn't exist that long)

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

checked Oracle documentation
tired to run the whole query both in Oracle SQL Developer and Python
it works perfectly fine in Oracle, but not in Python


NEVER use TO_DATE on a column that is already a DATE.
TO_DATE takes a string as the first argument and with you pass it a DATE then Oracle needs to convert it to a string so that TO_DATE can convert it back to a date - which either:

is pointless (as it was already a date); or

will cause errors (as is your case) because Oracle will convert your query to:
ROUND(
  MONTHS_BETWEEN(
    sysdate,
    TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR(
        c.registration_date,
        (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
      ),
      'dd.mm.yy'
    )
  ) / 12,
  1
)

and if the NLS_DATE_FORMAT does not match dd.mm.yy then it will either raise an exception or you will get an erroneous value.


In your case:

in SQL Developer, the NLS_DATE_FORMAT matches dd.mm.yy and the query works but the TO_DATE call is pointless.
in Python, the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is different and does not match dd.mm.yy so you are getting erroneous values.

To solve it, remove the TO_DATE:
ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, c.registration_date) / 12, 1) AS Years_Client


For example, if you have the data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (registration_date) AS
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1901-04-24' FROM DUAL;

and the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is YY-MM-DD then:
SELECT ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, TO_DATE(c.registration_date, 'dd.mm.yy')) / 12, 1)
        AS Years_Client,
       ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, c.registration_date) / 12, 1)
        AS actual_Years_Client
FROM   table_name c

Outputs



YEARS_CLIENT
ACTUAL_YEARS_CLIENT




4
0


23
.1


.1
123



fiddle

Thank you for your instant help! The magic has happened and I'm finally receiving correct calculations. Also big thanks for the additional information and explanation. Now, it is all much more clear "why".

Note that the default 'Thin' mode of python-oracledb uses Python functionality for date handling and will ignore NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  If you don't want to use Python date handling functionality, you can stick with the optional 'Thick' mode of python-oracledb that uses Oracle's NLS libraries.
